# What does attributte section mean in UEFI memmap?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded, uefi

When I call `memmap` in the UEFI shell, I got two different attributes like the following:

```
Shell> memmap
Type       Start            End              # Pages          Attributes
Available  0000000080000000-00000000CFFFFFFF 0000000000050000 000000000000000E
Available  0000002000000000-000000237FFFFFFF 0000000000380000 000000000000000F
```

The problem is that I cannot use the second region of memory whose attribute marks as `000000000000000F`. I've already registered that part of memory to my page table. But, my OS will panic when I convert a physical address from that region to a virtual address.

So, my problem is:

1. What does the attribute means?
2. How can I change the attribute so that I can use that part of memory?

Comment: The attribute values are shown in the `EFI_MEMORY_...` macros in "include/linux/efi.h" in the kernel source.

Comment: Attribute definition could be found in UEFI spec section 7.2, or P166 of [UEFI spec 2.8 Errata A](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_A_Feb14.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The `memmap` command displays the memory map that is maintained by the UEFI environment by listing the contents of EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR for each memory region.

```
typedef struct {
 UINT32                 Type;
 EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS   PhysicalStart;
 EFI_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS    VirtualStart;
 UINT64                 NumberOfPages;
 UINT64                 Attribute;
} EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR;
```

The Attribute field of a memory region describes the bit mask of capabilities for that memory region, and not necessarily the current settings for that memory region.

```
//*******************************************************
// Memory Attribute Definitions
//*******************************************************
// These types can be “ORed” together as needed.
#define EFI_MEMORY_UC            0x0000000000000001
#define EFI_MEMORY_WC            0x0000000000000002
#define EFI_MEMORY_WT            0x0000000000000004
#define EFI_MEMORY_WB            0x0000000000000008
#define EFI_MEMORY_UCE           0x0000000000000010
#define EFI_MEMORY_WP            0x0000000000001000
#define EFI_MEMORY_RP            0x0000000000002000
#define EFI_MEMORY_XP            0x0000000000004000
#define EFI_MEMORY_NV            0x0000000000008000
#define EFI_MEMORY_MORE_RELIABLE 0x0000000000010000
#define EFI_MEMORY_RO            0x0000000000020000
#define EFI_MEMORY_SP            0x0000000000040000
#define EFI_MEMORY_CPU_CRYPTO    0x0000000000080000
#define EFI_MEMORY_RUNTIME       0x8000000000000000
```

Full details about each of these attributes can be found in the UEFI Specification Section 7.2 under `GetMemoryMap`.

The only difference in attribute value between your two memory regions is EFI_MEMORY_UC, i.e. memory is not cacheable.